io.ktor.client.engine.darwin.DarwinHttpRequestException: Exception in http request: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"
@OptIn(ExperimentalForeignApi::class)
    actual fun getHttpClientEngine(): HttpClient {
        return HttpClient(Darwin) {
            engine {
                val builder = CertificatePinner.Builder()
                    .add("profile-storage.dev.test.com", "sha256/SEjJEk4siAhrAZkFl3jxcitQexznrspNp1oCV/kkw=")
                    .add("profile-storage.dev.test.com", "sha256//JHA1smVvlBr/Lgrj+yhezyHgTeiHwPAe8fcVMBgc=")
                    .add("profile-storage.dev.test.com", "sha256/Zr1x9sn87/3U0aW8JK+B9Y7isDZ/K6vSoCByzySPM=")
                    .add("profile-storage.dev.test.com", "sha256/wJjlj0thOszqFqWskpeZJb5qF1z1esbG1hk3+qq6g=")
                handleChallenge(builder.build())
            }
        }
    }

I spent the whole day trying to add an ssl certificate to the ios project. It turned out to be easy to add to android, I just added it to AndroidManifest, but with ios it turned out to be more difficult. Previously, I developed only for android and I don't know how to add ssl support to the project. I have four files with the crt extension. Where do I need to add them to make the network work?
I tried to redefine the ChallengeHandler, but with no result

Do you need to specify the certificate on the client for the Mutual TLS?
